# Can't Set Background of Grid. Possible Bug in WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have a bit of XAML in WPF like so

```
<TabItem Header="Remote Mode">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
     <Grid.Background>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="/ETest;component/Images/RemoteLarge.png"/>
     </Grid.Background>
   </Grid>
 </Grid>
```

Unfortunately, now, when I try to switch to the tab shown above, Visual Studio navigates to the code in the XAML, but refuses to switch to the tab in the designer. I've tried building the application and switching tabs from there too, but that doesn't appear to work either. Why can't I switch tabs now? If I remove the image from the XAML, I can switch tabs again.

**As a note**: The image itself is an 817x2167 .png. Could the problem possibly lie there?

**Edit**: I, unfortunately, don't have access to the original project until Monday. I have a copy of the image I was working with and tested using it in a basic WPF application. The following XAML works flawlessly:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="750">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Test1" />
            <TabItem Header="Remote Mode">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/RemoteLarge.png"/>
                        </Grid.Background>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'll try to post more of the original project when I get the chance. Perhaps the problem lies elsewhere in the application.

**Edit 2**: Here's the full XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ETest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:ETest.Controls.AutoSequence"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        MinHeight="550"
        MinWidth="835"
        Height="550"
        Width="835"
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
          Background="#C0FFC0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="23" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu Grid.Row="0">
            <Menu.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" 
                                     StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#E8E8E8" 
                                  Offset="0.528"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#F5F5F5" 
                                  Offset="0.01"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#E0E0E0" 
                                  Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" 
                                  Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Menu.Background>
        </Menu>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="1">
            <TabItem Header="AutoSequence">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" 
                             Grid.Row="0" 
                             Grid.RowSpan="2">
                    </ListBox>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,20,0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0">
                            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                   Content="Drag Steps Here to make an Autosequence" />
                            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                    Margin="0,0,0,4" 
                                    Width="100" 
                                    Content="Start Test"/>
                            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                    Margin="0,0,40,0" 
                                    Width="150" Height="23" 
                                    Content="**** Interface"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" />
                    </Grid>
                    <GroupBox Grid.Column="1" 
                              Grid.Row="1" 
                              Header="Step Configuration">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="23"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <DockPanel Grid.Row="0">
                                <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left"  
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                       Content="Step Name" />
                                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                        Width="75" 
                                        Content="Save Step" />
                                <TextBox />
                            </DockPanel>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                <c:Message/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </GroupBox>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Remote Mode">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/ETest;component/Images/RmtLrg.png"/>
                        </Grid.Background>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Edit 3**:

Things just got strange. I deleted the file, exported another copy from the original application, named it RmtLrg.png, added it, and the file failed to work. I tried double clicking the file in the solution explorer to view it, then switched back to my MainWindow in Visual Studio. The image was loaded in the designer and I was able to switch tabs as I normally would.

For all of a minute it was working, but, in a rush of excitement, I built the application. I attempted to switch tabs in it, but this failed. Checking back in the designer afterwards, I noticed the image is no longer loaded and I once again am unable to switch to the TabControl tab in question.

**Edit 4**:

The problem is still occurring and seems, quite literally, to be that the image is too big to set as a grid background (even if that makes no sense). I've tried Png, Jpg, and Gif formats and none work. Loading other, smaller images in the project works perfectly without issue.

**Edit 5**:

Oddly enough, loading a 3000x3000 image works perfectly. The only image that won't load so far is my 817x2167 image. Why could this be?

Comment: Here are a few things I would try... Import a 2nd image into your project, change the filename to the new name in the xaml and try again.  Then remove ImageBrush and try again.  Close Visual Studio and open again.  Close all windows in the project, close, open again.  Delete .SUO files and try again.

Comment: @IntStarFoo, just tested a smaller image and it appears to work just fine. Tried everything else you suggested, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Is it possible that you have attached a handler to the `SelectionChanged` event and are inadvertently stopping the `TabItem` from displaying by accident?

Comment: @Sheridan I've no event handlers yet. Outside of setting up a Ninject kernel and creating parts of the UI, I've not added any code yet. There aren't even bindings in place.

Comment: Size Related? [Make a copy of the image, rename, import it.  Does that work?  No?  Might be size related.]  That doesn't seem likely though.  817x2167 isn't too big.  How large is the file?

Comment: Make sure your `png` file has it's `Build Action` set to `Resource` in your project.

Comment: @HighCore It's set to resource. If it wasn't, a warning would appear in the XAML and the image would simply fail to load.